# How to turn off Visual Studio Web App SSL Warning Dialog for local development?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Version 17.8.5
When I run Debugger (or Start without Debugging) I get a Dialog:

[image]

I respond checking "Don't ask me again" and Yes.

then I get this:

[image]

And I click No.
Then I get this:
[image]

I click OK and the tab opens in my Edge browser.

how can I turn this off on my local machine? (This happens after every Build)

The projects are Net 6 MVC.

I have tried other responses to the dialogs but they result in lots of other issues with the SSL cert.

Thanks!!